# Is there a method to have a fixed full page background and an imageslider on one page?

Tags: jquery, css, slider, background-image, fullscreen

Working on a project I need a page with a fixed fullscreen background and an imageslider. I have tried many different plugins/techniques but I can't find a combination which is cross-browser compatible (at least on desktop).

Thinking this isn't a too uncommon layout I presumed finding an solution wouldn't be a big deal. But now I'm really stuck on this "little" issue.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Have you been able to get a fixed full page background?

Comment: Fixed background is not the problem. When adding the slider you need backface-visibility: hidden and that then messes up the fixed background in Chrome

Comment: Can you provide an example where it is messed up?

Comment: Currently: http://klanten.icu-media.net/wittehoeve